# How to fix jackson-databind version in spring-boot-starter-json pom.xml

Tags: spring-boot, security, jackson-databind

I want to fix vulnerability in my project created with spring-boot.

```
Vulnerable module: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind
Introduced through: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web@2.1.5.RELEASE and com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind@2.9.8

spring-boot-starter-json pom.xml doesn't contain version for jackson-databind artifact.
```

Can I add 2.9.8 and create PR to spring-boot 2.1.x branch?

Original POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starters</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
    <name>Spring Boot Json Starter</name>
    <description>Starter for reading and writing json</description>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../../..</main.basedir>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to exclude the jackson from your spring boot package. Then put jackson with new version separately in maven dependency. For instance:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
       <version>2.13.4</version>
   </dependency>
```